# Get SQL Query Data into HTML via PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm having a hard time pushing a ton of data from SQL into an HTML table.

I have a `chartbuilder.php` file which has this code in it:

```
$pieQueryCreates = "SELECT Count(Action) FROM dbo.File_System_Profiles WHERE Action like '%create%' AND (DATEDIFF(day,TimeOccurred,getdate()) between 0 and 30)";
$pieQueryResult  = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sQuery);

if ($pieResultCreates === false) {
    die(sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ERRORS));
}
$pieQueryCreateCount = sqlsrv_fetch_array($pieQueryResult);
```

This is my HTML:

```
<?php require '/php/chartbuilder.php'; ?>
<?php echo $pieQueryCreateCount; ?>
```

And I get nothing from the echo. If I echo `$pieQuerCreateCount[0]` I still get nothing from the echo. If I echo `$pieQueryResult` I get a `Resource ID #4` which isn't a surprise but leads me to believe the query is being completed. Copy/pasting my SELECT statement into SQL returns the count as expected in a single row/column with no name.

I just need to be able to access that one value and nothing I am doing seems to work, I've read through the documentation for [`sqlsrv_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) this multiple times and tried a variety of changes based on their examples to find no success.

Comment: Have you tried using `print_r` instead of `echo`?

Comment: what is `$sQuery`? shouldn't you use your `$pieQueryCreates` instead?

Comment: You should be getting errors both from trying to echo an array and using the wrong variable, as mentioned by @rbock. Please, [get error to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).

Comment: BTW: The statement `if($pieResultCreates === false){` is never true, since you used the wrong variable (should be using `pieQueryResult`)

Comment: Good eye rbock, didn't resolve my problem but was definitely a problem.

Comment: FirstOne you got me closer with the print_r, thank you for your assistance.  I'll work on the error display, didn't want you to think I was ignoring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your chartbuilder.php file generate an array with query results.

```
$pieQueryCreates = "SELECT Count(Action) FROM dbo.File_System_Profiles WHERE Action like '%create%' AND (DATEDIFF(day,TimeOccurred,getdate()) between 0 and 30)";
$pieQueryResult = sqlsrv_query($conn, $pieQueryCreates );
if($pieQueryResult === false){
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($pieQueryResult,SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
      $results[] = $row;
}
```

print_r($results); // check the array

Now in html display $results array in the way you like.
echo $results[0][0];

Comment: The `select count` would probably just have one row... So, assuming everything else is ok, calling `sqlsrv_fetch_array` once should be enough.

Comment: Yes if the result is one record, as @FirstOne said, there is no need of while loop. I have edited the code. changed $sQuery to $pieQueryCreates and error condition.

Comment: If I use your code (copy/paste) then do this in my html: <?php require '/php/chartbuilder.php'; ?> then <?php echo $results[0]; ?> it just prints "Array".

Comment: can you use print_r instead of echo. like print_r($results)

Comment: <?php print_r($results[0]); ?> does result in Array ( [] => 17115 ) being printed, that 17115 is what I'm trying to get into a variable.

Comment: I have edited the code, use SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC instead of SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC in while loop. and echo $results[0][0] in html.